# Generating TLS master key with smartcard using PKCS11

Tags: ssl, smartcard, pkcs#11

I am supposed to generate tls specific keys with smartcard.

I examined for example P11TlsMasterSecretGenerator class but it requires CKM_TLS_MASTER_KEY_DERIVE_DH mechanism that smartcard to have for master key generation.

But my smartcard does not support this mechanism.

My question is if it possible to use other mechanisms such as CKM_ECDH1_DERIVE for this purpose.

Actually my concern is what CKM_TLS_MASTER_KEY_DERIVE_DH mechanism provides internally more than CKM_ECDH1_DERIVE.

If someone can link me a document or something, I really appreciate that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

RFC5246 defines masterkey generation like this:

master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret,"master secret",ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random)[0..47];

where:

PRF(secret, label, seed) = P_hash(secret, label+seed);

P_hash(secret, seed) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(1)+seed) + HMAC_hash(secret, A(2)+seed) + HMAC_hash(secret, A(3)+seed) + ...

A(0) = seed
A(i) = HMAC_hash(secret, A(i-1));

So one can implement this algorithm by using HMAC on smartcard. But it does not solve my problem where I want master_secret to be generated in card and not extractable out of the smardcard. HMAC functions always outputs a byte array as a result as expected.